# How to set Cursor in TextField

Tags: swift, cursor, textfield

My ViewController contains a TextField. How can you make the Cursor go to the TextField ?

I am thinking of a method similar to this - but what to add for the Cursor to jump into the TextField allowing the user to start typing whenever this method is called ??

```
func reloadEntries() {
    self.txtfield?.becomeFirstResponder()
    ...
}
```

Comment: When I call that on a TextField, the use can start typing straight away because becoming first responder focussed the textfield and shows the keyboard. What's going wrong in your scenario?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Well, I use a tableView that creates its own container-textView. I guess this is the problem. With your help, I know now that an ordinary textField would eventually get the cursor with "becomeFirstResponder()". For the rest, I need to dig in a bit deeper...:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to call becomeFirstResponder() in viewDidAppear() and not in viewDidLoad() as you might encounter some issues. You can also call makeFirstResponder on the application window object and pass in your textField:

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0].makeFirstResponder(textField)
```